# I am running a python dash web app on GAE.It works well locally but an input box in the app does not react when I 1st try to type?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

On top of the title I actually need to "type" something (which does not appear) and press "go" for the app to begin to react. In fact then I can finally type and see my input  and get it to be read in by the program as expected. The app is currently hosted `@ https://foodmoodai.appspot.com/ . username : test , passwd : test1` , Enjoy it !

I've tried to change the initial state of the input box from `''` to `' '` to no avail. I've tried to increase the CPU resources thinking it was a performance issue.

My app.yaml file :

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn app:app.server -b :$PORT

threadsafe: false

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2


resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

the top of the code in Q (main file) :

```
import dash

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from textwrap import dedent as d
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from NutrientParser import parseNutrientStr_frmUser,parseResearch,parseFoodResearch,find_substring
from userMindfuleClasses import *
#import time
#import dash_table as dtable
#import base64
import PIL  
import urllib3
from PIL import Image
import json,os
import arrow

from server import app

colors = {
    'logo_font' : '#797d7f',
    'logo_background' : ' #f2f3f4',
    'submit_button_font' : '#fbfcfc',
    'blue' : '#4530CA'                                              
}


layout = html.Div([

    #html.Img(className = 'company_logo',
        #src = '/.name_company_logo.jpg',
        #style={
                #'height' : '8%',
                #'width' : '8%',
                #'padding-top' : 15,
                #'padding-bottom' : 20,
                #'padding-left' : 10
            #}),
    html.Div(children = [  
            dcc.Input(
                id = 'meal_input',
                placeholder = 'Start typing...',
                value='', 
                style={
                    'textAlign': 'left',
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                    'color' : colors['logo_font'],
                    'background-color' : colors['logo_background'],
                    'position' : 'absolute',
                    'top' : '100px' ,
                    'left' : '315px',
                    'width' : '300px',
                    'height' : '30px',

                })
        ]), 

    html.Div(className = 'row_submit_button', children = [  
            html.Button(......
```

expected result is for my attempted input text to appear and affect other components in the app just like it does locally. In actuality it just stays with it's initial text  "Start typing..." and does not react at all. No error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some JavaScipt errors happening on load:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined does not have a method named "concat"
    at bundle.js?v=0.12.1:2
    at e (bundle.js?v=0.12.1:1)
    at bundle.js?v=0.12.1:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at l (bundle.js?v=0.12.1:1)
    at bundle.js?v=0.12.1:2
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at bundle.js?v=0.12.1:2
```

Perhaps this is why?

Comment: Yeah I seen that but did not think it was the specific error, although actually it does make a lot of sense now that you point it out. But as I said it does not happen at all locally , in fact it undergoes the expected behaviour . Do you think it is maybe a javascript versioning error so or something like that maybe ...? Or has anyone seen an error like this and what was it down to ...(?)